# Xcode can't compile XIBs

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, xib

I'm getting the below error message and multiple XIB compilations failing with exit code 6. I can't make much sense of it. Anyone know what might be wrong?

I've cleaned the project, but that didn't help.

The errors only happen when archiving, not when simply running the app. EDIT: Scratch that, after I did the build (and clean), running no longer works.

```
CompileXIB MyProject/en.lproj/MainMenu.xib
    cd /Users/wesley/XCode/MyProject
    setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/wesley/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-ciandcogabqifsfgbscfrfgabfet/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyProject/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyProject.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MainMenu.nib /Users/wesley/XCode/MyProject/MyProject/en.lproj/MainMenu.xib --sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk

2013-04-09 09:48:22.377 ibtoold[77454:1207] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-3084/ibtool/IBToolErrorForwarder.m:32Details:  Unhandled error: 13Object:   <IBToolErrorForwarder: 0x401036100>Method:   -initThread:   <NSThread: 0x40030a1e0>{name = (null), num = 1}Hints: NoneBacktrace:  0  0x000000010c04c7c3 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundatio  1  0x000000010c04c5f4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundatio  2  0x000000010b571bba (in ibtool  3  0x000000010b569115 (in ibtool  4  0x000000010b563f74 (in ibtool  5  0x00000000000000Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASSERTION FAILURE CAUSES :-It could be the file you are opening or corrupted preferences. Try deleting preferences or opening a known good nib/xib file.

Also

Deleting everything in your "Derived Data" folder

Clean your project.
More similar question [xcode won't compile iOS apps, crashes when .xib or .storyboard files are opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109571/xcode-wont-compile-ios-apps-crashes-when-xib-or-storyboard-files-are-opened) helps you!

Also Try

removing all *.xcdatamodel directories that are not displayed in XCode from your *.xcdatamodeld directory. These directories appear after *.xcdatamodel renaming in XCode.

Comment: Thanks, I did some more testing, it happens even on new projects.. I uninstalled xcode and then reinstalled it, but the problem remains.

Comment: check now, i have modified the answer!

Comment: Thanks, didn't work initially, but after a restart it did. :)