# Xcode 6.1 crashes whenever I use Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, crash

Nothing I do works. I open Interface Builder on multiple different projects, all cause a crash. Same exception. I tried various solutions suggested on Google & SO, such as clearing the Derived folder (I actually cleared the whole `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/*` tree but still nothing). I'm really lost, and it's halting all development for me.

I opened a support ticket on developer.apple.com, but I haven't gotten a reply yet (been about 4-5 days now).

```
Process:               Xcode [10292]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.1 (6604)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6604000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       752282650
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [10292]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2014-11-27 11:48:15.688 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        F1E42FB4-8CFC-E112-4F9A-3286A610D4A0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       817AB1FE-F61F-4359-A845-094095FF399A

Time Awake Since Boot: 70000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       4700 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A1052d
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-6250/InterfaceBuilderKit/Document/IBDocument.m:5597
Details:  The pasteboard doesn't have data for this type: IBNSObjectPBType!
Object:   <IBXIBDocument: 0x7fcbb65d9200>
Method:   -insertObjectsFromPasteboard:ofType:asChildrenOfObject:atIndex:context:finishExtractingObjectsBlock:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fcbb3c389e0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001024199ea -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001011d7d1f _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001011d800e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010b2afcc8 -[IBDocument insertObjectsFromPasteboard:ofType:asChildrenOfObject:atIndex:context:finishExtractingObjectsBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  4  0x000000010b2af253 -[IBDocument insertObjectsFromPasteboard:ofType:asChildrenOfObject:atIndex:context:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5  0x000000010b2b0f1d -[IBDocument decodePasteboardContent:ofType:forInsertionInto:usingDocumentClass:andDocumentType:context:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6  0x000000010b2b23f7 __86-[IBDocument documentWithPasteboardCloneOfObjects:documentClass:documentType:context:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7  0x000000010b1b9a34 +[NSPasteboard(IBPasteboardAdditions) invokeWithTemporaryPasteboard:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  8  0x000000010b2b22e0 -[IBDocument documentWithPasteboardCloneOfObjects:documentClass:documentType:context:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9  0x000000010ffc5ecc -[NSObject(IBCocoaAutolayoutEngineAdditions) ibCopyObjectHierarchyForLayoutEngine:synchronousDidCopyCallback:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 10  0x000000010ffc6f5f -[NSWindowTemplate(IBCocoaAutolayoutEngineAdditions) ibWindowWithCopiedViewHierarchySnapshotForLayoutEngine:returningAddedRepresentedConstraintsForRepresentedViews:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 11  0x000000010ffc761b -[IBCocoaAutolayoutEngine prepareViewHierarchyAndReturnAddedRepresentedConstraintsForRepresentedViews] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 12  0x00000001075fa556 -[IBAutolayoutEngine initWithArbitrationUnit:options:] (in IBAutolayoutFoundation)
 13  0x000000010ffc7538 -[IBCocoaAutolayoutEngine initWithArbitrationUnit:options:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 14  0x0000000107603422 -[IBAutolayoutFrameDecisionDriver initWithArbitrationUnit:initialStatus:options:] (in IBAutolayoutFoundation)
 15  0x000000010b1dda80 -[IBAutolayoutFrameDecider initWithArbitrationUnit:driverOptions:delegate:statusInitializationBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 16  0x000000010b1de170 +[IBAutolayoutFrameDecider decideAndSetFramesOfAllViewHierarchiesWithLayoutInfo:delegate:statusInitializationBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17  0x000000010b2d31e9 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager runBlockInNewArbitrationStackEntryWithBehavior:block:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18  0x000000010b2ba1f7 -[IBDocument modifyViewsInAutolayoutSafeWayWithoutUpdatingConstraintsDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 19  0x000000010b310670 -[IBDocumentVerifier verifyViewsHaveCorrectFrames] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 20  0x000000010b30d2ed -[IBDocumentVerifier verificationDidFinish] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 21  0x000000010b30d008 -[IBDocumentVerifier performVerification] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 22  0x000000010b2ac610 -[IBDocument performVerification] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 23  0x000000010b280da2 __39-[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 24  0x000000010b2de6e0 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager doNotSynchronouslyComputeAutolayoutStatusWhilePerformingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 25  0x000000010b280bc1 __39-[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
```

Comment: Did you try to reinstall Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I did. I trashed it, cleared the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode` folder, and re-downloaded from the app store. Didn't change anything

Comment: Did you try Xcode 6.2 beta?

Comment: No, I will try to download it now

Comment: Doesn't work, it still crashes :/

Comment: A restart works for me at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

It has something to do with Autolayout.

1- Right click the storyboard file -> Open As -> Source Code then find and remove  useAutolayout="YES"

2- Right click the storyboard file -> Open As -> Interface Builder

This worked in my case, however, I'm unable to get the autolayout to work :)

Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26474823/1231121

**Edit 1:**

After many tries and searches I managed to get this resolved by:

1- Completely remove Xcode.app (from terminal sudo rm -rf /Applications/Xcode.app/)

2- Install it again

3- Restarted my MBP

then everything back to work as expected.

**Edit 2:**

It happened again, a mac restart resolved it!

Comment: Seems to be working for now. Is autolayout on for new projects by default? Because this would explain why even opening a new project, doesn't solve it.

Comment: Yes, Autolayout is enabled by default starting from xCode 5.