# Cannot change file in Xcode project

Tags: xcode

When I launch one of my Xcode projects, I am presented the storyboard of the project. I can edit the storyboard, I can run the project on my device and simulator. But on changing to any other file from the project navigator or any other way (like opening any file of my project from finder), I get stuck with a rolling rainbow cursor which keeps on rolling till infinity (I have waited for as long as an hour) and I have to force quit Xcode. My other projects appears to work fine.

I have tried the following fixes:

1. Restarting my Mac
2. Reinstalling Xcode
3. Resetting Xcode Settings from http://ioslau.blogspot.in/2013/08/resetting-xcode-settingspreferences.html

I have Xcode v6.3 and Yosemite v10.10.3.

I don't want to recreate my project as it will suck time. 
Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to open a new tab (or window) and _then_ switch to another file? Also, you could try deleting the derived data for this project (via Window > Projects in the latest Xcode or Window > Organizer in the previous versions)

Comment: @Alladinian Neither of them works. I also tried to create a new file so that Xcode switches to it but it creates the file and then hangs again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a known issue with the latest release of Xcode:
[apple dev forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1125061#1125061)

Comment: [Also found this discussion to be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542356/xcode-6-3-crashes-when-navigating-from-storyboard-to-other-swift-1-2-file)

Comment: The first solution in the link helped me escape the rolling rainbow cursor trap. It seems the problem was with the IB_Designable I was using. After deleting the UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate, I removed all the IB_Designable code and that brought everything back to normal. Thanks for directing me to the link.

Comment: Great, glad it helped.This has been a really irritating problem for me as well.

Comment: Xcode update 6.3.1 is out and seems to have resolved these issues.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer and the apple dev forum didn't help me.
I am using a swift project with no IB and no Storyboard.

What I did was, close Xcode, restart the mac, open the Xcode not from the app but form the .xcodeproject file. It worked.

Comment: Xcode could freeze because of many reasons so the accepted answer may have not worked for you. That's why I tried to be as specific as i could to explain my problem (which was related to IB_Designables in storyboards).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to make a copy of the files that were uneditable, delete the original files from the Xcode project and drag the duplicates in.