# Xcode 6.3 storyboard stuck

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.3

When I open storyboard, the XCode shows that it's building right now, I suppose because of IBDesignable I use.

So it never got success, XCode stuck:

[image]

I tried to open just storyboard file with opening entire project, so seems it works, but when I try to close it, it's starting stucking again, I can't close it, and it every time in my process.

I tried restarting my mac, deleting xcuserdata, but nothing help to me.

It's upset because I written entire project using storyboards and now I can't continue to work on the project =(

One more when I try to open another file and I am in storyboard right now, like selecting a class or project file it also stuck. (switching from storyboard)

Comment: The Apple dev forums a full of similar complains. Maybe you can find there a temporary solution.

Comment: @dasdom Good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542356/xcode-6-3-crashes-when-navigating-from-storyboard-to-other-swift-1-2-file

Open new window in XCode answer.