# Unable to build in xcode due to exit code 255

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I had developed an app in xcode 4.6.3 around an year back. Due to some requirement I had to make changes to it but now when I tried to open xcode 4.6.3 on yosemite then it's crashing and also the code is getting build in xcode 5 or 6. In both I am getting error. I am also not able to open storyboard as it hangs xcode till it crashes. I have already searched on SO regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422033/why-am-i-getting-ibtool-failed-with-exit-code-255) but none worked. Below is the error message. Also I have tried to re-install xcode 5/6 many times.

```
CompileStoryboard BigFootApp/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard
    cd /Users/ankurbansal/iOS/BigFootV14
    setenv IBSC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 6.1 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/ankurbansal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BigFootApp-ffxdxncphppzxialoqqybopmrdjp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BigFootApp.app/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboardc /Users/ankurbansal/iOS/BigFootV14/BigFootApp/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard

Assertion failed: (host_bootstrap_port != MACH_PORT_NULL), function _sim_host_bootstrap_init, file /SourceCache/Interposition_Sim/Interposition_Sim-111/libSystem/system/bootstrap.c, line 26.
2014-12-21 00:57:30.919 ibtoold[1262:66852] Init failed: Error Domain=IBMessageChannelErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)"
2014-12-21 00:57:30.919 ibtoold[1262:66852] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3742/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:313
Details:  IBAttachToCocoaTouchTool() failed: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator." UserInfo=0x7fb12a6906a0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb12a69f370 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason="Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (1271) failed to launch and exited with status (null), signal 6.}
Function: IBMessageChannelCocoaTouchToolProxy *IBAttachToCocoaTouchToolFailingGracefully(IBCocoaTouchTargetRuntime *__strong, NSError *__autoreleasing *)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb12a43a3b0>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2014-12-21 00:57:30.965 ibtoold[1262:66852] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3742/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:36
Details:  Failed to launch cocoa touch tool: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator." UserInfo=0x7fb12a6906a0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb12a69f370 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason="Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (1271) failed to launch and exited with status (null), signal 6.}
Object:   <NSThread: 0x7fb12a43a3b0>
Method:   -cocoaTouchToolForTargetRuntime:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb12a43a3b0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010d2d0bdd -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x000000010d2d0655 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010d2d0984 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000112056536 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  4  0x00000001120562c5 IBAskClassInTargetRuntimeForValueForKeyPathUsingResultMarshallerWithContext (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  5  0x00000001120561ed IBAskClassInTargetRuntimeForValueForKeyPathUsingResultMarshaller (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  6  0x000000011209c5ea (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  7  0x00000001120556ed (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  8  0x000000011209c921 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  9  0x000000011209ac95 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 10  0x000000010c6afb02 __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 11  0x000000010c6ae026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 12  0x000000010c6af94d -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13  0x000000010c6b2179 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectForKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14  0x000000011206973d (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 15  0x000000010c6afc6a __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 16  0x000000010c6ae026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17  0x000000010c6af94d -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18  0x000000010c6b10ce -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectArrayOrDictionaryFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 19  0x000000010c6b0543 __50-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 20  0x000000010c6ae026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 21  0x000000010c6b02b8 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 22  0x000000010c6b2328 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayWithName:forOptionalKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 23  0x000000010c43da24 -[NSView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) unarchiveWithDocumentUnarchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 24  0x00000001120748a1 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 25  0x000000010c6afc6a __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 26  0x000000010c6ae026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 27  0x000000010c6af94d -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 28  0x000000010c6b2179 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectForKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 29  0x000000011207558b (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 30  0x000000010c6afc6a __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 31  0x000000010c6ae026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 32  0x000000010c6af94d -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 33  0x000000010c6b10ce -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectArrayOrDictionaryFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 34  0x000000010c6b0543 __50-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 35  0x000000010c6ae026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 36  0x000000010c6b02b8 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 37  0x000000010c6b1789 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayWithName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 38  0x000000011218c172 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 39  0x000000010c6ae026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 40  0x000000010c6b4021 -[IBDocumentUnarchiverGroupMember(unarchiveContentWithBlock) unarchiveContentWithBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 41  0x000000011218bfbb (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 42  0x000000010c6b1d39 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver enumerateGroupMembers:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 43  0x000000011218be93 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 44  0x000000010c6ae026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 45  0x000000010c6b1b23 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver enterGroupWithName:optionalKey:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 46  0x000000011218bdf0 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 47  0x000000010c453feb -[IBDocument unarchiveDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 48  0x000000011218c66e (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 49  0x000000010c6ae026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 50  0x000000010c6ae28b -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 51  0x000000010c44c5d3 __81-[IBDocument decodeContentFileWrapper:fileDataType:typeName:decodingStyle:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 52  0x000000010c480b14 -[IBDocument runBlockInNewArbitrationStackEntryWithBehavior:block:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 53  0x000000010c44c2c8 -[IBDocument decodeContentFileWrapper:fileDataType:typeName:decodingStyle:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 54  0x000000010c44c835 -[IBDocument readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 55  0x00007fff8cbb793f -[NSDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
 56  0x000000010c444110 __39-[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 57  0x000000010c478612 -[IBDocument invokeWithUndoSuppressed:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 58  0x000000010c443e5f -[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 59  0x000000010c243712 (in ibtoold)
 60  0x000000010c23f1e0 (in ibtoold)
 61  0x000000010c244c21 (in ibtoold)
 62  0x000000010c24f23d (in ibtoold)
 63  0x000000010c24f781 (in ibtoold)
 64  0x000000010c24f654 (in ibtoold)
 65  0x000000010c24dade (in ibtoold)
 66  0x000000010c24eeb2 (in ibtoold)
 67  0x000000010c24e610 (in ibtoold)
 68  0x00007fff891235c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about what's happening with Xcode 5 & 6, but Xcode 4 is no longer working on Yosemite. Even freshly installed Yosemite and it refuses to run XC4. A lot of others ran into that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few re-install it worked. I am not sure how but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Google "IBAttachToCocoaTouchTool" as its stated in the crash report
2. Clean Derived Data: Window->Organizer

[image: where to remove derived data]

3. Reset Content & Settings of iOS Simulator

[image: where to reset simulator]

4. If you have Total Commander and its feature Assepsis than follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225606/2648673)