# ‘Cloud/CLAPIEngine.h’ file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

My application has been running fine with the Cloud-iOS.a library for the past few days. However, today, when I used the “Product > Clear Build Folder” command and tried to run the app again, it would give me this error:

```
‘Cloud/CLAPIEngine.h’ file not found
```

The Cloud library builds successfully, but the main project gives me that error along with 4 others in both the main project and the XCTest files (that are linked with this one).

I’ve tried removing and re-inserting the file from Build Phases > Headers and Build Phases > Compile Sources and that didn’t do anything (I also have tried to remove the -fno-objc-arc flag from the file to see if it would recognize it, and sure enough, it gave me an ARC error). I’ve tried looking through other SO questions like these:

- [Restkit/Restkit.h file not found Xcode 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971258/restkit-restkit-h-file-not-found-xcode-6-1)
- [Adding frameworks to project in Xcode 5 and having *relative* paths added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109085/adding-frameworks-to-project-in-xcode-5-and-having-relative-paths-added)

... and nothing worked. I even tried restarting the app itself and nothing happened. I made a test project and included the same library to see if it’s my project, but this project also says the same errors. Both projects also have the file in the "include/" directory. I don’t know why this is happening and I’m starting to get really tired with Xcode’s random problems.

I’ve included the test project in a Dropbox link for others to check out and see why it’s doing this.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lu8hntaaww8y6r4/AAA1KJ085YvKjwMR-AZff6Nga?dl=0

What can I do to get this to run again? Thanks in advance.

*(After this, I’m not running the “Clear Build Folder" command again.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Looks like [someone over at Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1109590#1109590) was able to give me an answer. I chose the last one that they gave me, which was to change the static library into a framework. Thank goodness Apple made this available on iOS, because (after a bit of tweaking), everything works!