# ProcessInfoPlistFile couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: xcode, macos

Saw this build Error in my XCode 6 project.
ProcessInfoPlistFile 'couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.'
Noticed that it was referencing a non existant .plist in myproject-etmdzgntrsozugsfwdahjbpsyjze folder.
Cleaning (Cmd+Shift+K) and Option cleaning (Opt+Cmd+Shift+K) the project and then rebuilding did not fix it.

The project still builds and runs but that error is worrisome.

Answer (score 1):

Noticed that I had a build up of files in 
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
including.
myproject-etmdzgntrsozugsfwdahjbpsyjze

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279141/what-can-i-safely-delete-in-my-library-developer-xcode-deriveddata-directory), I saw that it was safe to:

1. Close XCode
2. go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
3. delete all the contents
4. Reopen XCode
5. Rebuild the projects

After some lengthy reindexing the rebuild succeeded and the error is gone.
My project builds and runs as normal.

Comment: This actually works when i deleted all the files in build folder