# iOS9 Segueing from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, ios9, uistoryboard, xcode7, uistoryboardsegue

I have this simple Storyboard:
[image: Storyboard]

When I set the segue type between middle Controller to right one (ctrl+drag from prototype cell -> adaptive show segue type), my detail view is sliding from bottom of screen, not slide from side. When I use deprecated push segue everything works like expected but I have warning for using old type.

How I can make sure that new type of segue will be working like deprecated push one?

Comment: Not sure if you've tried this, but you might want to close Xcode. Then, nuke derived data. Type `cmd + shift + g` from Finder and go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. Nuke that and try opening the project again and cleaning caches when you open it.

Comment: @AdrianB I can try, but what is that DerivedData? And how to clean cache after opening? I have seen big thread on Apple dev forum about it. I couldn't find answer there.

Comment: Here's a thread that explains it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7284632/4475605 Based upon what you describe, what you're doing ought to work. When I've encountered weird behavior and I'm certain it's not an error on my part, I've found cleaning derived data usually resolves the problem. Cleaning the cache can be done with `cmd + shift + k`

Comment: Are you sure that you are using push not modally?

Comment: @SeanChense I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

Select desired segue -> Utilities -> Attributes inspector -> Kind -> Show (e.g Push)[image]