# Warnings in app.dsym in Xcode after update

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Since I updated Xcode to the latest version I get a lot of warnings and I could not find clear explanation/solution, first it used to be just when I was testing on simulator but now I also get it when testing on device.

[image]

I tried this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17921 but it did not helped me that much, I managed to get rid of the warning from the app extension but not the app itself. Anyone who encountered similar problem and managed to solve it?

Comment: Have you solved it? I am having the same problem too.

Comment: Well , I did re download the older simulators and after I did set the build settings again as in the link above and it seems to be fine now , no warnings and behave as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to changes in the build process across different Xcode versions, I am having this problem again with version 8.3.3 (8E3004b), so **if this is happening just after an update** you can fix it shutting down Xcode and deleting folder

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

which gets created again after the first build. 
About the risks of deleting that folder you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279141/how-can-i-safely-delete-in-my-library-developer-xcode-deriveddata-directory)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Targets -> [your project] -> Build Settings
2. Find and expand "Debug Information Format"
3. Change "Debug" value to "DWARF"
4. I left "Release" value unchanged as "DWARF with dSYM File"

I read that Debug builds don't need dSYM files.