# how to fix linker command failed with exit code 1 error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have created the project, when I am trying to run the project I get the following error and build fails.

```
ld: file not found: /Users/mohammad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SPA-clncipsgigcqmgaourubdrurgfyz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SPA.app/SPA
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: it said it can't find library `AFNetworking`. How did you install this lib?

Comment: please check `AFNetworking` is in your build settings.

Comment: import your AFNetworking library correctly and make sure Xcode find that library

Comment: guys I got new error!!!

Comment: check afnetworking library files... are they present at their location?

Comment: check out this link for successfully integrating AFNetworking in your Xcode project    http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk_afnetworking--mobile-10741  @blacktiger

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma edit my question my error is : ld: file not found: /Users/mohammad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SPA-clncipsgigcqmgaourubdrurgfyz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SPA.app/SPA
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: clear your derived data of app

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma how to clear derived data my app??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder.... check here

Answer (score -1):

when i got this type of error , i was removed derived data folder from following path :

```
/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

see this link for more help

[How can I safely delete in my ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279141/)